# info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Tags: git, cgit

I found this page
https://cgit.kde.org/kcachegrind.git/?h=Applications/15.04
can anybody tell me how to git clone from the site?
I tried `git clone https://cgit.kde.org/kcachegrind.git` but it gives me

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ckim/Downloads/kcachegrind/.git/
fatal: https://cgit.kde.org/kcachegrind.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

I searched on the web about this, but could not find the solution that applies to me.

Comment: *You* cannot fix this; only the people who run `cgit.kde.org` can fix this. You can try contacting them and alerting them to the problem.

Comment: ok, I got it. (I got the impression earlier). BTW, I found kcachegrind had been installed in my system I have used it yesterday. Thanks.